# How can I select a set of IDs from large table fast?

Tags: mysql, performance, where-in

I have a large table with ID as primary. About 3 million rows and I need to extract a small set of rows base on given ID list.

Currently I am doing it on  where... in but it's very slow, like 5 to 10s.

My code:

```
select id,fa,fb,fc 
from db1.t1 
where id in(15,213,156,321566,13,165,416,132163,6514361,... );
```

I tried to query one ID at a time but it is still slow. like

```
select id,fa,fb,fc from db1.t1 where id =25;
```

I also tried to use a temp table and insert the ID list and call Join. But no improvement.

```
select id,fa,fb,fc from db1.t1 inner join  db1.temp  on t1.id=temp.id
```

Is there any way to make it faster?

here is table.

```
CREATE TABLE  `db1`.`t1` (
  `id` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(1024) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastUpdate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `lastModified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Ok here is explain select.

```
id=1,
select_type='SIMPLE', 
table='t1', 
type='range', 
possible_keys='PRIMARY', 
key='PRIMARY',
key_len= '4',
ref= '', 
rows=9, 
extra='Using where'
```

Comment: Hm, PK should always be indexed but from your description sounds like not. What indexes do you have?

Comment: It have ID as primay key. I think it mean it is indexed. correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: SHOW INDEXES FROM db1.t1;

Comment: is this InnoDB or MyISAM?

Comment: Also run `EXPLAIN <your query>` and post results in your question in a textual form

Comment: It doesn't add up there is no `urlId` column in your `CREATE` statement that you mentioned in `PRIMARY KEY (urlId)`

Comment: Try using InnoDB and compare performance.

Comment: The table is quite big. Just conversion could take hours. It is about 60gb now. I hope there is other choice. else I will try test out tonight.

Comment: What does `SELECT @@key_buffer_size;` say? Is your table actively inserted into/updated while you select from it?

Comment: key_buffer is 512M and Key buffer fraction 18%.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips how you can speed up the performance of your table:

- Try to avoid complex SELECT queries on MyISAM tables that are updated
  frequently, to avoid problems with table locking that occur due to
  contention between readers and writers.
- To sort an index and data according to an index, use `myisamchk
  --sort-index --sort-records=1` (assuming that you want to sort on index 1). This is a good way to make queries faster if you have a
  unique index from which you want to read all rows in order according
  to the index. The first time you sort a large table this way, it may
  take a long time.
- For MyISAM tables that change frequently, try to avoid all
  variable-length columns (`VARCHAR`, `BLOB`, and `TEXT`). The table uses
  dynamic row format if it includes even a single variable-length
  column.
- Strings are automatically prefix- and end-space compressed in MyISAM
  indexes. See [“CREATE INDEX Syntax”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html).
- You can increase performance by caching queries or answers in your
  application and then executing many inserts or updates together.
  Locking the table during this operation ensures that the index cache
  is only flushed once after all updates. You can also take advantage
  of MySQL's query cache to achieve similar results; see [“The MySQL Query Cache”.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-cache.html).

You can read further on this articles on Optimizing your queries.

- [MySQL Query Cache](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/27/mysql-query-cache/)
- [Query Cache SELECT Options](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/27/mysql-query-cache/)
- [Optimizing MySQL queries with IN operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408250/optimizing-mysql-queries-with-in-operator)
- [Optimizing MyISAM Queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-queries-myisam.html)

Answer (score 0):

First of all clustered indexes are faster then non-clustered indexes if I am not wrong.
Then sometime even you have index on a table, try to create re-index, or create statistics to rebuild it.

I saw on SQL explain plan that when we use where ID in (...), it converts it to 
Where (ID =1) or (ID=2) or (Id=3)..... so bigger the list many ors, so for very big tables avoid IN ()

Try "Explain" this SQL and it can tell you where is the actual bottle neck.
Check this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html
hope will work

Answer (score -1):

Looks like original sql statement using 'in' should be fine since the Id columns is indexed

I think you basically need a faster computer - are you doing this query on shared hosting?

Comment: well it is i7 with 16gb ram on the SSD. Actually I got this on development box and also testing on vps. VPS seem to be slightly better some how.